# Is this correct punctuation for the sentence?

Tags: punctuation

Is this correct punctuation for the sentence?  I called it the,"Witch's tree."

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more appropriate for ELL.

Comment: You shouldn't have a comma after 'the'. It is British practice to place the closing quotation mark after the full stop in cases like this.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: Regarding the full stop, I was under the impression that AmE puts the period inside quotes in most cases. Are you saying that BrE puts it outside when using quotes to denote a specific name or title?

Comment: I can confirm, in AmE we would typically put the period inside the "quotes."

Comment: British practice is to place inside the quotation marks only that which appears in the words being quoted.

Answer (score 2):

No. The correct way to punctuate this sentence is either of the following:

> I called it The Witch's Tree.
>
> I called it "The Witch's Tree." (American English)
>
> I called it "The Witch's Tree". (British English)

Comment: He should also, if he wants it to be a proper noun, caplitalize "The Witch's Tree" as such....not sure about the period inside the quotation marks, but it should be fine that way.

Comment: Yeah, the capitalization is all messed up but that is a different question so I decided not to mess with it too much. But I think you're right and will edit appropriately.

Comment: I think you should probably mention the BrE perspective regarding that period inside the quotes. I know that's how Americans usually do it, but it always looks a bit weird to me.